# Creating new entries based of old entries and another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Table A and Table B.

Table A contains an ID. For every ID in Table A there are up to (sometimes less) 12 entries in Table B. I now need to create 6 new entries in Table B based on the 12 old ones from Table B. For some entries the correlation is 3:1 for some its 1:1. I always have to pick the highest value out of the old entries.

[image: Example]

I made an easy example. Table A has the ID 1000. But there are many more entries in table a ofc. For now we just look at the one entry. Table B then contains the same UniqueID and the Same Department. First the Category in Table A gets changed to 321.

In Table B we look at the Values that have the same unique ID and same Department. We will find up to 12 entries (11 here). I have a table of correlations now. For the example we say that Category 554 and 663 correlate to category 1 of the new entry. I then pick the highest value out of those 2 and that's the value for the new entry. 445 and 654 correlate to 2 so the highest value is a 2 now. And so on.

I kinda have to iterate through the whole Table A and don't really know how that would go. Also just to be sure I only included the entries from unique id 1000 in Table B but 1001 and 1002 are ofc also present there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want to create new rows in B.  But then A changes and the number of rows in B goes down.

Comment: So i had some errors in the picture. I corrected them. But for the background. Department 10 will be integrated into department 321. For Table A that is done but just changing the department from 10 to 321. 

For Table B for every Unique ID from Table a there are up to 12 entries. In the new Table B we will have new categories (1-6). To find out what to put as value for the new categories i have a correlation matrix. So for example for the entry of category 1 i look at at the old category 554 and 663 and take the max value of those two. In the end we delete the old rows from Table B.

Comment: Hi @Odatas, please can you show us your script that you have tried already. Also, could you edit your question to detail the desired outcome please, as it's not currently all that clear to understand. [advice on providing an MRE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You say 554 and 653 correlate to 1 and 445 and 654 correlate to 2 - how do they correlate? I am assuming the 10 -> 321 is arbitrary and predetermined outside of this data? It looks like you are picking every two records and pairing them to get a valueof the max(val) of the two, and incrementing a new category sarting with 1. Is this the case - if so, are these pairings ordered in some way?

Comment: Yes the 10 to 321 is predetermined. The Category numbers for TableB After is arbitrary right now. In reality i also have predetermind numbers there. And for the corelation its really copying the whole row and changing the department to 321. So i copy from 554 and 653 for category 1 the whole row and change the department to 321. For which value to copy i in dee look at max(val). I will try to provide a MRE and futher explenation later.

Comment: You still haven;t explained how you are selecting which two to group together - it appear almost random.

Comment: It is also predetermined. There is no logic there. I would have guessed you can just do a randome selection and from there i could work it out. If you need the exact correlation i could provide it.